# Fetch unique object based on attribute name from coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have entity employee_detail in coredata

```
name | rate | factor |
_______|______|________|
John   |  3.2 |    4   |
Betty  |  5.5 |    7   |
Betty  |  2.1 |    2   |
Betty  |  3.1 |    2   |
Edward |  4.5 |    5   |
John   |  2.3 |    4   |
```

i want unique object base on attribute name

O/P should be

```
name | rate | factor |
_______|______|________|
John   |  3.2 |    4   |
Betty  |  5.5 |    7   |
Edward |  4.5 |    5   |
```

Comment: You should use DISTINCT <fieldName> in your query for getting this type of result

Comment: i have try that. but still not working

Comment: then you have to manage manually, like adding into one temp array new values and use that

Comment: i have done same as u thinking but i don't want to go manually bcoz some time have thousands of duplicate record then it take too time for filter it manually.

Comment: data fetching from Core-data framework

Answer (score 2):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"employee_detail"];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"employee_detail" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;

NSArray *dictionaries = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSLog (@"names: %@",dictionaries);
```

Comment: it just resulting name only. i want that object not only that column.

Comment: Have you found the answer? @Yagnesh Dobariya

Comment: @YagneshDobariya Please share your idea with here.

Comment: for loop with array of objects employee_detail. Initially as per example array will have 6 object of type employee_detail. Manage one temp array. write for loop with array object 6 object and check object available in temp array. If not add object in temp array otherwise continue to next object in loop. Final temp array will be the output.